# Invalid unicode while sending a POST request to django with libcurl and jsoncpp

Tags: c++, django, django-rest-framework, libcurl, jsoncpp

I've created a REST endpoint in Django using the rest-framework module; the simple code goes as below:

models.py

```
class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ('name', 'description')
```

views.py

```
def data_list(request):
    """
    List all data.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        categories = Data.objects.all()
        serializer = DataSerializer(categories, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = DataSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

I've tried sending POST requests using the RESTClient plugin for Firefox, and can validate that it works as-is.

However, my use-case is that I'd like to write to the database using libcurl in a C++ application.

If I use jsoncpp to create a JSON object, and then use libcurl to make a POST request, as below:

```
void main() {
    Json::Value submitted_data;
    submitted_data["name"] = "data id";
    submitted_data["description"] = "data description";
    Json::StyledWriter writer;

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/");
        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, writer.write(submitted_data).c_str());

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}
```

I get an error from the django server:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\parsers.py", line 67, in parse
    raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % six.text_type(exc))
ParseError: JSON parse error - 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

And the post request isn't successful.  My understanding is that:

- django-rest-framework expects a utf-8 encoded json string,
- jsoncpp encodes strings in utf-8, and
- libcurl is agnostic about encoding and deals with data at the byte level.

so I'm a bit surprised by this and not sure how to begin troubleshooting.  Can someone help me figure out how to have my C++ application and django application work together?

thanks!

Comment: Capture the network traffic by running the code via `strace`, or some other means. You'll probably find that one of your assumptions is wrong, and you're emitting ISO-8859-1 encoded data.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm running the application on Windows 10, and was disappointed to find that Wireshark doesn't seem to be able to capture loopback traffic.  Do you have any recommendations for something I can use on Windows?

Comment: You don't have to send the request to the same Windows box. Send it to some other Windows or Linux box.

Comment: Loopback traffic does not go out through any network interfaces, so Wireshark cannot capture the traffic.  But, if you define a local network route that bounces loopback traffic off of a network device, like a LAN router, then it can capture that traffic (and then you can just filter out the duplicate packets).

Comment: Assuming that this was the issue, how would I fix it?  The `JSONParser` class doesn't seem to take any encoding parameters; is it easier to force jsoncpp to encode it as utf-8 or to write my own custom parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html):

> **The data pointed to is NOT copied by the library: as a consequence, it must be preserved by the calling application until the associated transfer finishes**. This behaviour can be changed (so libcurl does copy the data) by setting the `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` option.

You are passing a *temporary* `char*` pointer to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.  This is because `Json::StyledWriter::write()` returns a *temporary* `std::string` that you are then calling `c_str()` on.  When the call to `curl_easy_setopt()` is complete, that `std::string` gets destroyed, and thus the `char*` pointer that curl is holding on to is no longer valid.  Curl ends up transmitting garbage data from freed memory.  This is *undefined behavior*, you are lucky your code did not just crash altogether.

So, you need to either:

1. preserve the `std::string` in a local variable until `curl_easy_perform()` is finished:

   ```
   std::string json = writer.write(submitted_data);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json.c_str());
   ```
2. use `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` instead of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:

   ```
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, writer.write(submitted_data).c_str());
   ```

Comment: In my case i was trying to make a request to a node js http server, but i got the same error, so i tried this solution and now its fine; Thanks so much!